# Read variable values from the file path

Tags: java, string, variables, path, filenames

I would like get variable values from a file name. 
For example, I have a folder of images with 2 sub folders called "photos_2011_mycamera" and "photos_2012_mycamera". I want to be able to read the year and then I will use it with the photos inside the folder. I was thinking in something like tokens where you can put
**$** and this would read the number in $ and take it as a variable (in this case the years 2011 and 2012).
I'm guessing that I will have problems with variables at the end of the path, not properly separated...
I use Java, but the problem would be the same in any other language, I guess.
I would appreciate any suggestion or tips of the best way to do this.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Where are you thinking of using the $ as a placeholder in the names of the files on your disk?

Comment: it would be nice to see some examples and code here...

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you already have the file name in a variable called *FileName* you can use the split() method in Java to split up the string and add the different substrings to an array.

For example:

```
String FileName = "photos_2011_mycamera";
String type, year, name;

String[] dataArray = FileName.split("_") // Splits the string wherever a "_" occurs
type = dataArray[0];
year = dataArray[1];
name = dataArray[2];

System.out.println(type); //photos
System.out.println(year); //2011
System.out.println(name); //mycamera
```

Assuming your files will always be named in that format this method souhld work fine.